# HTTP Call Returning Stale Data

Tags: java, android, http

I'm building an application that retrieves data at a set interval from a website and I'm retrieving stale data. Specifically, I'm pulling scores from NFL games but whenever the score changes, my application alternates between returning the old score and the new score. Eventually, it will stabilize and only return the new score.

How do I prevent my application from returning stale data?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String webSourceCode;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   new MyAsyncTask().execute(); 

}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Integer>> {
    protected List<Integer> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL nfl = new URL("http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/scoreboard");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            nfl.openStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        webSourceCode = sb.toString();

        return parseScores(webSourceCode);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Integer> listScores) {

        updateViews(listScores);
        //recursion
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET calls can be cached by server or intermediaries. You can pass a dynamic query parameters to ensure that the intermediary/server does not send back a cached response. Something like this will work:

```
URL nfl = new URL("http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/scoreboard?nocache="+new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to try it out when the next game comes out and I'll accept your answer if it works.